# Use of icon fonts and links

Tags: icons

When using an icon font and text for a link, do they both get styled for link interactions?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For visual consistency its preferred to both have the same style, this will help the user to associate both elements to the same action.

However this might depend on the icon look and feel, if it has colours it can work on its own without losing the association with the text as a link/button.

Let me illustrate what I'm saying.

Solid icons should be styled for "link interactions" as they don't work well on their own due to the lack of its own colors.

[image]